# Any Red5 Working Example Project for 0.9 release

Tags: apache-flex, flash, red5, flash-media-server

I'm trying to find 1, just 1, working sample project for Red5 that's updated to work against the latest 0.9 release without missing jars and other nonsense.

Right now, it's at v0.9 and the libs are different from other versions. They have 5 pathetic examples on their website, but all were built with the older versions. For these 5 old examples, I could use the Add External JARS feature to try and add libs from previous versions, they don't mention which versions they were built against and I'm not going to try each previous version to see which works (I already did and nothing works). They don't seem to be putting any effort into updating or marketing their open source project.

**Anyone who's more intelligent and can shed some light on behalf of these fools?**

Comment: I agree with you that the Red5 project is pretty much a big f'ing mess. I love the idea of Red5 but every time I try it out (like just now 0.9.1) I end up screaming my head off. There is not a single "properly" working example that doesn't involve a large amount of black magic to get it to work. It's a shame because if they'd put in a bit more effort than people might actually use it.

Comment: Yeah, I have played with it for days and it's like beating your head against a wall. I am almost ready to give up and go to either the adobe option or electro server, the only thing that worries me about electro server is that it has not been updated in 3 years.

Comment: Wow, being a red5 core developer I guess I could take offense with the comments and the question but I wont. Neither of your names look familiar to me so I would image you didn't bother to join the mailing list? 
All that aside, I'll see what I can do to address your question.

Comment: The mailing list is here: http://groups.google.com/group/red5interest
I personally just started using stackoverflow regularly and since I am the only regular dev on the project I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 4):

What sorts of issues are you having?  What sorts of projects are you trying to build?

I'm by no means an expert on this - and I admit that the lack of documentation is pretty frustrating.

However, I just downloaded [their latest](http://code.google.com/p/red5/), installed it and got the olfa demo running pretty seamlessly.

The source for the demos are [available here](http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/java/example/trunk/?r=3355), and I use these to work out what I need.

Comment: We do provide eclipse project files and ant build scripts, in addition to ivy configs. I do admit that we don't keep up with the docs, but we try.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.smartfoxserver.com/ makes use of red5 in someway. Perhaps you can find something useful in their (well documented) examples, good luck.